# jersey web client exception

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

i have jersey client code as follow

```
    public static void callWebServicePost(String xml) {

    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());

    try {
        MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
        formData.add("xml", xml);

        System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("path1")
                .path("path2")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .post(String.class, formData));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static URI getBaseURI() {
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/store").build();
}
```

Now when i call the method callWebServicePost and pass a xml string to it i got follow exception

```
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
```

and the stack tarace is as follow

```
 com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected  end of file from server
     at     com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:151)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:568)
at    com.tainosystems.main.WebServiceClient.callWebServicePost(WebServiceClient.java:71)
at com.tainosystems.main.WebServiceClient.main(WebServiceClient.java:99)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:769)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:632)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:766)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:632)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:249)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
... 6 more
```

Comment: which version of jersey-client are you using?

Comment: And can you post your server side code?